# Use Paypal - Connected Path Upfront Onboarding through PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm following this tutorial on [Paypal's developer website](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/upfront/#1-make-a-partner-referrals-api-call) to make a partner referral call.

This is the code I'm using on PHP

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "tracking_id":"MyTrackingId",
    "operations": [
      {
        "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
        "api_integration_preference": {
          "rest_api_integration": {
            "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
            "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
            "third_party_details": {
              "features": [
                "PAYMENT",
                "REFUND",
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "products": [
      "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
    ],
    "legal_consents": [
      {
        "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
        "granted": true
      }
    ]
}',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'accept-language: en_US',
        'authorization: Bearer MySecretCode',
        'content-type: application/json',
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($response));
    echo '</pre>';
}
echo '<hr>';
```

and this is the response I'm getting:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => INVALID_REQUEST
    [message] => Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.
    [debug_id] => 9e151f0c8c5f0
    [information_link] => 
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [issue] => INVALID_PARAMETER_SYNTAX
                    [description] => Referral data is not a valid json object.
                )

        )

    [links] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm not sure whether it relates to the code in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.  I tried modifying it and using online curl to PHP converters but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: json is not valid `"REFUND",`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for getting back to me... I tried a JSON validator but I'm stuck on that error. How can I fix it, please?

Comment: remove the trailing `,`